# Why does Django makemigrations think I renamed a field when adding to a model

Tags: django-models, makemigrations

After adding fields to a model, makemigrations asks me if I renamed a field when I just added to the model. It lists the field name a Campaign.not_a_real_field renamed to some_other_field_name where some_other_field_name is nowhere in the models.py

I expect makemigrations to simply add the new fields.